# npm install esbuild-* unsupported warning

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I just upgraded my angular from 10 to 12 from https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=10.0-12.0 and every step was successful and now npm install is giving bellow warnings:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-android-arm64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-android-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-android-arm64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-32@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-32@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-ppc64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ppc64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-mips64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"mips64el"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-openbsd-64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-openbsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-openbsd-64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"openbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-sunos-64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-sunos-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-sunos-64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-windows-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-32@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-windows-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-32@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-arm64@0.13.4 (node_modules/esbuild-windows-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-arm64@0.13.4: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~12.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.10",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.1.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

I searched the error but couldn't find any solution

any idea how to fix these warnings?

Answer (score 15):

```
npm cache --force clean && npm install --force
```

worked for me

Comment: it is resolved for me ,good!

Answer (score 4):

You can force the installation

```
npm install -f
```

and for the next installation should work without the -f flag. other solution is that you can fix the version to **12.1.4** where there is no dependencies to esBuild

Comment: should i fix angular version to 12.1.4?

Comment: no just force the install

Comment: This is not an error to force it with npm install -f it's a warning and i just needed to fix it.

Comment: downgrading the angular to `12.1.4` worked for me on my M1 MacBook 2020

Answer (score 0):

Update NPM, if you haven't for a while. The optionalDependencies stuff they rely on isn't supported in ancient versions. In my case, npm version 6.14.16 wasn't enough.

Updating to 8.19.2 did the trick.